# simple way to select only rows of df1 where combination of columns is present in df2 (NOT joining df1, df2)

Tags: r

Imagine I have two data frames, with two or three common variables, but many more different variables:

```
df1=data.frame(a=rep(c(3000,4000,5000),each=4),b=c(50,60),c=1,as.list(colnames(mtcars)))    
df2=data.frame(a=c(3000,4000),b=60,c=c(1,2),as.list(LETTERS))
```

I want to select only the rows of `df1`, where the combination of value for `a` and `b` is present in at least one row of `df2`, without caring about `c` (the remaining common column). If I use

```
merge(df1,df2,by=c("a","b"))
```

the right rows get selected, but...ALL the columns of `df2` are added to `df1`. That's not what I want. In the real case, `df2` and `df1` can have ~ 1000 columns each, whose names can change at runtime, and at most 2 or 3 columns have the same name. Thus I should find an automatic, adaptable way to remove little less than 1000 columns, which are in `df2` but not in `df1`. This seems slow and complicated (also, I have no idea how I could do that). Isn't there a simpler solution which doesn't add the extra columns to `df1`?

Comment: `df1[df1$a==df2$a & df1$b==df2$b,]` ?

Comment: @Tensibai it works! For some stupid reason I tried `df1[df1$a %in% df2$a & df1$b %in% df2$b,]`, which of course doesn't work, then I went the `merge` way, but I forgot about the obvious way. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, previous version was a misuse of data.table syntax (or a with/by syntax)

Comment: hmmm, when applied to the real (much bigger data frames) it didn't work. I must have left out some important detail, when preparing my minimal case. I'll close the question and open a better one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can also use `semi_join` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
semi_join(df1, df2, by = c("a", "b"))
#     a  b c X.mpg. X.cyl. X.disp. X.hp. X.drat. X.wt. X.qsec. X.vs. X.am. X.gear. X.carb.
#1 3000 60 1    mpg    cyl    disp    hp    drat    wt    qsec    vs    am    gear    carb
#2 3000 60 1    mpg    cyl    disp    hp    drat    wt    qsec    vs    am    gear    carb
#3 4000 60 1    mpg    cyl    disp    hp    drat    wt    qsec    vs    am    gear    carb
#4 4000 60 1    mpg    cyl    disp    hp    drat    wt    qsec    vs    am    gear    carb
```